# How to handle UTC math using date-fns library in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, utc, date-fns

I'm trying to use the `date-fns` library to add and subtract dates, but it doesn't handle UTC dates correctly. For example:

```
> const { add } = require('date-fns');
undefined
> s = new Date('2021-03-27')
2021-03-27T00:00:00.000Z
> add(s, {days:1})
2021-03-28T00:00:00.000Z
> add(s, {days:2})
2021-03-28T23:00:00.000Z
```

The issue is that my dates are in UTC, and I want to do UTC date arithmetic on them, but as soon as they're converted to a date/time they get treated as local dates. This is a problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make all your operations, and at the end of your function, call the method toISOString() of the final date object. It'll return the UTC 0 value.

And remember that the date object you've passed by parameter to `add` function is never changed, the returned value is what you want.

Comment: `add(s, {days:2}).toISOString()` in the above example returns `'2021-03-28T23:00:00.000Z'` — so it doesn't work.

Comment: Basically, it looks like the `add` function is adding a day in the local timezone, which is following Daylight Savings time, which then calculates the wrong time in UTC.

Comment: Hmmm, right.

Could you please try `new Date('2021-03-27T00:00')` instead of `new Date('2021-03-27')`, using toISOString function also? Something like that:

`const s = new Date('2021-03-27T00:00');
const parsedDate = add(s, {days:2}).toISOString();
console.log(parsedDate)`

Comment: Still no good. Adding `00:00` to the end makes the date `2021-03-26T22:00:00.000Z` which turns into `2021-03-28T21:00:00.000Z` when you add two days.

Comment: Ok, could you tell me what timezone is your server? I'll try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I'm currently in EEST